# Why does the code : os.popen('move *.bin tmp) only move one file?

Tags: python

all,

Currently, I write a python code in WIN, i'd like to run the command line code

```
move *.bin tmp
```

but only one file was removed.

How can I make popen to finish this task?

Best wish!

Comment: Show some code! We are just guessing what and how you did it!

Comment: If any of the answer helped you than accept it. If you got any question add a comment to that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using Pythons own modules instead of Windows tools (as also Patrick suggest). I think something like this will work:

```
import glob
import shutil

dest = 'c:/tmp/'

# Get all the files as a list with glob
files = glob.glob('c:/files/*.bin')

# move each file seperatly
for filename in files:
    shutil.move(filename, dest)
```

Or to make it short:

```
import glob, shutil
for f in glob.glob('c:/files/*.bin'):
    shutil.move(f, 'c:/tmp/')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `move` process is waiting for you to read its output.

I suggest to use the `subprocess` module instead and call `communicate()` ([example](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline); just ignore the part about `p1` and omit `stdin=p1.stdout,` in your code).

Answer (score 1):

shutil.move(src, dst)
Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst).

If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, 
then src is moved inside that directory.

The destination directory must not already exist. If the destination 
already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten 
depending on os.rename() semantics.

If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. 
Otherwise, src is copied (using copy2()) to dst and then removed.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, and 'shutil' is helpful for my task.